# Printing lines from a file in Java

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I am making a method that prints lines in a file which contain a certain word. If the parameter is an empty String, it is supposed to print the entire file.

I've gotten the first part to work. Everything in the "else" statement works great; it scans each line and prints the lines that contain the word in the parameter.

BUT I can't get it to print the whole file when an empty String ("") is entered as the parameter "word". I'm not sure why this is.

```
public void printLinesWhichContain(String word) {
    while (this.reader.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = this.reader.nextLine();
        if (word.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(line);
        } else {
            Scanner lineReader = new Scanner(line);
            while (lineReader.hasNext()) {
                if (lineReader.next().equals(word)) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly do you call the method printLinesWhichContain? printLinesWhichContain(""); ?

Comment: Try `"".equals(word)`..

Comment: This method works fine for me if I pass empty String `""` as its argument. Can you show us how you are using it?

Comment: I think You need to press ctrl+i to enter empty line

Comment: Rather than creating a new scanner every time use `if(line.contains(word)) System.out.println(line);` otherwise the rest of your code is fine.

Comment: Well I feel like an idiot guys. The code works fine. There must have been a typo in my main method. I think it was something involving the character set, as I'm using a Spanish computer and they have different quotation marks. No pasa nada.

Comment: Actually, that wasn't the problem. I've noticed in my main method that if I call printLinesWhichContain("some word"), and THEN call it on an empty String, it won't work. Otherwise it will. I'm lost as to why.

Comment: EDIT: I figured it out. I had to create the Scanner WITHIN the method. If I create it outside the method, it reads through the File the first time it's called and then that's it. This way it starts at the beginning every time.

Comment: and if you try two call printLinesWhichContain("some word") and then printLinesWhichContain("someOtherword") what happens? The second call works or not? Maybe the problem is not about the empty string but about your reader, do you have implemented your own reader? Maybe the reader is not 'reset', and for these reason it works only once the first time.

Comment: Because this.reader.hasNextLine() at second time don't have anything to read

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the line in String format, you can use the indexOf method to get the index of the word.

I wouldn't create a Scanner for each and every line.

I mean you might want to change the else part as follows.

```
int indexOfWord = line.indexOf(word);
            if (indexOfWord >= 0) 
            {
                 System.out.println(line);
            }
```

Comment: This is not relevant to what the question asks.

Comment: It will print the line if the argument is "". Isn't that what the question is about?

Comment: and if the word is not an empty string "" but is a word not contained in the line? It will print the line, and this is not correct

Comment: Corrected. Thanks. Changed if (indexOfWord != -1) to if (indexOfWord >= 0).